# Custom URL for Google Apps

Tags: g-suite, google

Requirement: I want to create custom URL to access my company google apps account.
Ex: mail.companyname.com

Effort made: https://support.google.com/a/answer/53340?hl=en

Error : users are still able to access email from gmail.com

Expectation:Employees should be able to access email through this custom URL only.

Comment: Hi Here is what i tried, https://support.google.com/a/answer/53340?hl=en     But end users are still able to access email from gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

The original google URL will always still work.  Your custom URL doesn't replace it, but works in addition to it.